# Scala - testing function that return json as string

Tags: scala, scalatest

im trying to learn how to write good tests in general. I happen to write a function in Scala and I want to make sure the model that is returned from the function matches with the model that I define in the test case. here is an example json that is returned from the function

```
[ 
   { 
      "id":1,
      "uuid":"11111-1111111-11111111-11111111-11111",
      "name":"test",
      "type":"doc",
      "contact":"abc@example.com",
      "expires":213293842,
      "user":1,
      "ad":[ 
         "test.com"
      ],
      "details":{ 
         "creation_time":1123212324,
         "agent":2,
         "apps":{ 
            "type1":{ 
               "mode":"standard"
            },
            "type2":{ 
               "mode":"non-standard"
            }
         }
      }
   }
]
```

can I please get some help on how to test my model to make sure I account for model changes during testing

btw, I found this git https://github.com/stephennancekivell/scalatest-json but I cant figure out how to implement it

Comment: If you are using a library to create your **JSONs** I would not test them, since the json generation was already tested by the library. So instead, I would decouple your function from that part and instead of returning a `String` it should return an instance of a **case class** which then will be used to create the **JSON**. You still should test the json but as part of an integration test. - If you are not using a library for creating the json then use one.

Comment: my function calls out to a service to get the json string output from the service. I want to make sure if anything changes in the service w.r.t json data model, I would like to catch that with my tests. With that said, I still dont understand and need help on how to write a good test

Comment: Well, first of all, your function shouldn't be that tightly coupled to that external service. You should build an abstraction an pass an instance of that abstraction to your function. Second, you should be operating raw **JSONs**, your abstraction should return a **case class** and the production implementation of such abstraction _(which is the one that calls the service)_ should use a library to parse the json into an instances of the case class. Now your function is completely isolated and its functionality can be tested in an unit.

Comment: For testing changes in the json you write an integration test for the production implementation of your abstraction. If the external service changes then the library will fail to parse the json as the case class you asked. BTW, you may be interested in [this](https://blog.7mind.io/constructive-test-taxonomy.html).

Comment: Thanks for making it clear to me. That is an awesome blogpost!